# Why does dotnet new webapi cause an error on restore?`

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and have following sdks installed

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.405 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.102 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

When I try to create a new Web API project I get an error

```
$ dotnet new webapi -f net7.0
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Restoring /home/dxxxx/dev/play/webapi7.0/webapi7.0.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/NuGet.targets(676,5): error : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: add [/home/dxxxx/dev/play/webapi7.0/webapi7.0.csproj]
Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
$
```

Comment: Not sure what other bugs might be happening, but do you get the same error if you run `dotnet new webapi -f net7.0 -o InsertDesiredProjectNameHere`?

Comment: Using the -o option results in the same error:-(

Comment: Have you tried opening `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/NuGet.targets` and looking at the line number in the error?

Comment: Is this a bug for .net 7? I mean will  the command work well when you create new project in .net 6? By the way, have you tried to create a project in another folder?